# Obtener numero de "onClick" sobre un "boton, imagen o texto" dentro de un fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Quiero conocer o capturar el evento "onClick" producido sobre esta imagen "(R.id.img_back_account)" para meterlo dentro de un "if" y asi poder realizar dos acciones diferentes, como mostrar y ocultar algo, se puede hacer eso??

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.img_back_account).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Toast.makeText(context, "Messages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((ProfileActivity)Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setupMainViewPager();


        }
    });
```

Comment: Quieres hacer una acción si la imagen recibe clic?

Comment: Quiero hacer algo si recibe 1 click y otra si recibe 2 clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabiendo ahora que lo que necesitas es: **cambiar de fragment uno por otro con el mismo clic**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out);
                if (fragment.isHidden()) {
                    ft.show(fragment);
                    button.setText("Hide");
                } else {
                    ft.hide(fragment);
                    button.setText("Show");
                }
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
```

Es un ejemplo de como puedes lograr hacerlo. Saludos.

Comment: Amigo yo solo necesito tocar un boton para mostrar un fragment y luego volver a tocar el mismo boton para ocultar el mismo fragment.

Comment: Entonces deberías hacer mejor el planteamiento en tu pregunta @FabianFigueroa por que me dijiste que con un clic una cosa, y con 2 clics otra, el planteamiento es: un clic hace algo y si lo vuelvo a hacer clic haga otra cosa. Te recomiendo actualizar tu pregunta.

Comment: Amigo es lo mismo, pero bueno, sabes como se podria hacer eso?

Comment: @FabianFigueroa probaste mi respuesta actualizada?

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez podrías hacerlo con un `switch`:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.img_back_account:
                    tucodigo;
                break;
            }
     }
```

Comment: Quiero hacer algo si recibe 2 clicks.